# Improving the OLAP operation performance

Tags: performance, pentaho, olap-cube, mondrian

I am developing OLAP based report which has drill down and slicing on large database(PostgreSQL) which has millions of records.
Currently,I am using following terms:

1. Pentaho BI suite 4.8
2. Saiku plugin
3. schema workbench 3.4 for developing OLAP cube.

I have following relational structure(PostgreSQL 9.1):

1. sales_fact-fact table which have location_id,customer_id,sales_amount,payment_amount
2. Location-has levels of Country,State,City,location_id
3. Customer-has Customer_name and customer_id
   I have maintained foreign key and proper indexing on fact as well as dimension tables.

My system configuration is as below:
OS:Linux Mint 16 Petra
RAM :4 GB
HDD : 500 GB
processor :intel core i3

But,when i am fetching analysis report(In Saiku plugin) using MDX on mondrian OLAP cube,it takes more and more time(almost 5 mins).Same result fetching time using SQL is around 1 mins.
What can i do for retrieving data within a fraction of seconds??so that my mdx OLAP cube will give better response time.
Or any other option available so that i can achieve the same goal???
Please suggest me if any option available.

Comment: Question too vague. Which query is taking long to run? What server is the DB running on, how much ram, etc? Plus, there isn't a one size fit all solution to this question. Optimising a data warehouse is not just "here, do this and it'll run fast".

Comment: PostgeSQL was never been efficient for me (for OLAP). Even MySQL (both MyISAM and InnoDB) was 50-150% faster. Yes, good indexing and data warehouse design does matter, but if you want performance - try HP Vertica. Same SQL syntax, just great performance!